# Assosiate values to variables in a .txt file (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to read different values from a .txt file and associate them to a dynamic variable to plot "temp vs absorver" and "temp vs layeropticaldepth" the problem is that i can't make a loop to diferencie the 3 channels

The .txt file is like this:

```
TEMPERATURE PROFILE 1 CHANNEL           1\n

  -4.2990996184651597E-008  -3.7630694837428993E-008  -2.8528269884920730E-008  -1.4347061145870253E-008   6.7381299583350918E-009   3.7384472759442260E-008\n

ABSORBER H2O PROFILE 1 CHANNEL           1\n

  -3.9565642128147107E-005  -4.7873606803926964E-005  -5.6805359720655236E-005  -6.6988031806236901E-005  -7.8741820957000240E-005  -9.2505348800073727E-005\n

LAYER OPTICAL DEPTH CHANNEL           1\n

   7.7647310213335644E-009   1.3237191385751397E-008   2.1779592801787183E-008   3.4483606665587544E-008   5.2872000616083457E-008   7.9082157903339866E-008\n

TEMPERATURE PROFILE 1 CHANNEL           2\n

  3.3244281640990698E-004   3.5861917706254720E-004   3.8570316070815153E-004   4.1377129909932360E-004   4.4230768213110238E-004   4.7093014085048985E-00\n

ABSORBER H2O PROFILE 1 CHANNEL           2\n

  7.6496658502447334E-006   9.0418128755558448E-006   1.0627911845440123E-005   1.2414997098262057E-005   1.4401618685172090E-005   1.6610800001542054E-005  \n

LAYER OPTICAL DEPTH CHANNEL           2\n

   7.7647310213335644E-009   1.3237191385751397E-008   2.1779592801787183E-008   3.4483606665587544E-008   5.2872000616083457E-008   7.9082157903339866E-008\n


TEMPERATURE PROFILE 1 CHANNEL           3\n

  -4.2990996184651597E-008  -3.7630694837428993E-008  -2.8528269884920730E-008  -1.4347061145870253E-008   6.7381299583350918E-009   3.7384472759442260E-008\n

ABSORBER H2O PROFILE 1 CHANNEL           3\n

  3.3244281640990698E-004   3.5861917706254720E-004   3.8570316070815153E-004   4.1377129909932360E-004   4.4230768213110238E-004   4.7093014085048985E-00\n

LAYER OPTICAL DEPTH CHANNEL          3\n

   7.6496658502447334E-006   9.0418128755558448E-006   1.0627911845440123E-005   1.2414997098262057E-005   1.4401618685172090E-005   1.6610800001542054E-005  \n
```

This is the code i have used until now

```
import re
filp = open("ATMS3.5.txt", "r")
lines = filp.readlines()
dicc = {}
values = {}
for i, lines in enumerate(lines):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        key = line
   else:
       values = re.findall(r'\d+', data)
   dicc.update({key:values})
lines    
values = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}', lines)
```

Please help

Comment: `dicc.update({key:values})` nooo just: `dicc[key] = values`

Comment: If that's what your input looks like, your code isn't going to parse it properly, because `i % 2 == 0` is false for both the key lines and the lines of numbers; the only even lines are the blank ones. (That's assuming the `\n` are actually a backslash and an n, not a newline; otherwise, things are even more screwy.)

Comment: Also, why is this tagged both python-3.x and python-2.7? Do you need to write dual-version code that works even though you're opening the file in Unicode mode in 3.x and bytes in 2.x? Do you think your problem has something to do with that attempt?

Comment: my mistake, is just for python 2.7, and thanks for the help